# .net mvc3 mysql table without primary keys

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, primary-key

I am new to .net and the only experience I have is with an MVC3 Entity Framework Code First project. I need to write a new web app that will query an existing legacy database. I have read only access to this MYSQL database. Most tables have no primary keys. I can connect to the DB okay. When trying to wire things up with EF and pull some data , I get errors that the the tables have no primary keys. Researching this issue on the web has brought me to the conclusion that I probably cannot use EF in this case. Given my limited experience, what would be my next best course of action? Any assistance would be appreciated.

Kindest Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use ADO.NET, which is built into the .NET framework. It will mean that you will have to write SQL code to interact with the database.

To get ADO.NET to work with MySQL, you'll need the MySQL ADO.NET [connector](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/). More documentation on ADO.NET can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e80y5yhx%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Given the read only access to a DB without primary keys, Entity Framework won't help you. I haven't tried it by myself, but I suggest you try using XSD files to create tableadapters and tables for your mysql pendants. But even if this works, without keys you won't be able to add any associations.